# what is the location of this docRoot variable?

Tags: java, javadoc

Using JavaDoc, I am trying to add a CopyRight notice on my source code; for that I have added the following line:

> CopyRight see the a href="{@docRoot}/C:/Users/ArbolOne/Documents/Dev/Java/CopyRight/JME_LICENSE.html">Copyright.**

This does not work, and clinking on the link will only display a web page saying "File not found".

However, it works if I change the line to:

> CopyRight see the a href="{C:/Users/ArbolOne/Documents/Dev/Java/CopyRight/JME_LICENSE.html">Copyright.**

Obviously this is not a desirable solution, thus my question, how can I change this line so that {@docRoot} points to the right place? and furthermore, what is the location of this docRoot variable?

I am using Eclipse/Java 10 on a Windows machine.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `{@docRoot}/C:/...` looks a little odd, does it really look that way in your code? If so that's most likely the problem. That being said, if you just use `{@docRoot}` in the Javadoc you should see that it's the source directory your code is in (i.e. where the top level package is located).

Comment: I followed the example on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#docRoot

Comment: Well, that example has `{@docRoot}/copyright.html` - no `C:` in there.

Comment: Yaaah, it means {@docRoot}/URL, and 'cos I don't know to what directory name the docRoot points to, I cannot add the html file to that directory, or change the docRoot to point to where the external documentation is.

Answer (score 4):

The [Javadoc tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#docRoot) says it clearly:

> Represents the relative path to the generated document's (destination)
>   root directory from any generated page.

The important thing here is that it is a ***relative*** path, which points to the same directory no matter what page of your javadoc you're in.

For instance, the value of `{@docRoot}` in the page for `java/lang/Object` would be `../..`

Similarly, in the page for `java/util/logging/Logger` it would be `../../..`

Your problem is that you are using a construct that specifies a ***relative*** path to specify an ***absolute*** path to `JME_LICENSE.html`

It would be easier and more practical for you to add a step in your build process to copy `JME_License.html` to the root of the generated Javadoc, and refer to it as `{@docRoot}/JME_LICENSE.html` from any Javadoc comment.

Comment: Using an IDE like IntelliJ, {@docRoot} references the root folder with all the java source files, for example src/main/java.